# dividing with highest value from mysql cell

Tags: php, mysql

i want to give rating to student so need to divide by highest marks achieved by topper is respective subject.
once i want to divide by smallest no also. i dont want to do multiple query.

here is the table

```
id  name        physics math
1   Adam        68      80
2   Mark        55      97
3   Luis        78      44
4   Philip      99      62
5   James       59      89
```

my php code is

```
  $re99 = "SELECT * FROM `tableA` order by id desc limit 10";
while($row2 = $res2->fetch_assoc()){

$name=$row2['name'];
$physics=$row2['physics'];
$math=$row2['math'];

$grade=$physics/99+$math/97;

$poor='poor performer in math is mark with 55 marks and Luis with 44 marks';
}
```

i dont know how to get these 4 values(99,97,55,44) from above table in one query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `select *, max(physics) as high_physics, max(math) as high_math, min(physics) as min_physics, min(math) as min_math from tableA order by id desc limit 10;`

Then you can do something like `$grade = $physics / $row2['high_physics'] + $math / $row2['high_math'];`

Comment: trying. seems u r master of sql

Comment: do you want realy to have 10 rows in your result or only the 2 poorest

Comment: @BerndBuffen i want to give grade to all so i want all 10 rows

Comment: @shane above query results only one row for one student with all minimum and maximum but how to get the details of other rows. i need to make other query?

Comment: @tumbin Yeah that's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you looking for. I have insert some more columns as a example. you can delete them if you not use it.

**Query**

```
SELECT
    ta.*
    , m.*
    , ta.physics / m.max_physics as grade_physics
    , ta.math / m.max_math as grade_math
    , ( ta.physics / m.max_physics ) + ( ta.math / m.max_math ) as grade
FROM tableA ta
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT max(math) as max_math, max(physics) as max_physics from
           (SELECT * from tableA order by id LIMIT 10) as x) as m
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 10;
```

**Sample Table**

```
mysql> select * from tableA;
+----+--------+---------+------+
| id | name   | physics | math |
+----+--------+---------+------+
|  1 | Adam   |      68 |   80 |
|  2 | Mark   |      55 |   97 |
|  3 | Luis   |      78 |   44 |
|  4 | Philip |      99 |   62 |
|  5 | James  |      59 |   89 |
+----+--------+---------+------+
5 rows in set (0,01 sec)
```

**Result**

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     ta.*
    ->     , m.*
    ->     , ta.physics / m.max_physics as grade_physics
    ->     , ta.math / m.max_math as grade_math
    ->     , ( ta.physics / m.max_physics ) + ( ta.math / m.max_math ) as grade
    -> FROM tableA ta
    -> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT max(math) as max_math, max(physics) as max_physics from (SELECT * from tableA order by id LIMIT 10) as x) as m
    -> ORDER BY id
    -> LIMIT 10;
+----+--------+---------+------+----------+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+
| id | name   | physics | math | max_math | max_physics | grade_physics | grade_math | grade  |
+----+--------+---------+------+----------+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+
|  1 | Adam   |      68 |   80 |       97 |          99 |        0.6869 |     0.8247 | 1.5116 |
|  2 | Mark   |      55 |   97 |       97 |          99 |        0.5556 |     1.0000 | 1.5556 |
|  3 | Luis   |      78 |   44 |       97 |          99 |        0.7879 |     0.4536 | 1.2415 |
|  4 | Philip |      99 |   62 |       97 |          99 |        1.0000 |     0.6392 | 1.6392 |
|  5 | James  |      59 |   89 |       97 |          99 |        0.5960 |     0.9175 | 1.5135 |
+----+--------+---------+------+----------+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```